# UNION ALL date on the same row

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, pivot, timestamp

I am unioning multiple tables together in Postgres, where the timestamp is slightly different, but the same if I round to the hour. Is it possible to make each union show on the same row, if the date is the same? Currently I'm getting duplicate rows of each date.

```
select date_trunc('hour', TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp), 
COALESCE(count(*), 0) as "1489",
null as "1616"
from actions
where group_id = 1489
and TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp >= current_date-7
group by 1
union all
select date_trunc('hour', TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp), 
null as "1489",
COALESCE(count(*), 0) as "1616"
from actions
where group_id = 1616
and TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp >= current_date-7
group by 1
order by 1
```

It returns:

[image]

Comment: I see potential time zone problems in your query. Are you operating with UTC? And there may be a faster solution, yet. But there is no table definition and not even your version of Postgres. Minimum requirements ... And please *always* post data as *text* not as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FULL JOIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) like this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(a1.t, a2.t) as t,
    a1."1489",
    a2."1616"
FROM
(
    select 
        date_trunc('hour', TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp) as t, 
        COALESCE(count(*), 0) as "1489"
    from actions
    where group_id = 1489
        and TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp >= current_date-7
    group by 1
) as a1
FULL JOIN
(
    select 
        date_trunc('hour', TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp) as t, 
        COALESCE(count(*), 0) as "1616"
    from actions
    where group_id = 1616
        and TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp >= current_date-7
    group by 1
) as a2 ON (a1.t=a2.t)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Or just use [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE):

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('hour', TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp),
    SUM(CASE WHEN group_id=1489 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1489",
    SUM(CASE WHEN group_id=1616 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1616"
FROM actions
WHERE 
    group_id in (1489, 1616)
    AND TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp >= current_date-7
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Assumptions

- Current Postgres 9.6.
- `actions.created` is a `bigint` column holding a count of ms since 1970-01-01 UTC (epoch in microseconds).
- `actions.groupid` is `integer`.

The basic query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', to_timestamp(created / 1000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS hour  -- !
     , group_id
     , count(*)::int AS ct       -- count never returns NULL
FROM   actions
WHERE  group_id IN (1489, 1616)  -- more?
AND    created  >= EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date - 7) * 1000  -- !
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

#### Major points

Don't make your query depend on the time zone setting of the session or you may be in for surprises: The result changes with the setting. Remember that "today" is a function of the time zone you are in. Detailed explanation:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Replace 'UTC' in above query with the time zone you want your times and dates to reflect. Use a ***time zone name*** (not an abbreviation) to be perfectly sure.

- [Time zone offset with surprising result](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160065/time-zone-offset-with-surprising-result/160083#160083)

Transform the `WHERE` condition:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(created / 1000)::timestamp >= current_date-7
```

to the equivalent:

```
created >= EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date - 7) * 1000`
```

That's generally faster and can use an index on `created`. (Makes it "[sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable)".)

Depending on data distribution, size of the table and typical you may want a multicolumn index on `(group_id, created DESC)` to optimize read performance. Performance optimization depends on the complete picture, though ...

The aggregate function `count()` never returns NULL. `COALESCE(count(*), 0)` is useless noise and can safely be replaced with just `count(*)`.

- [Query optimization or missing indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33612/query-optimization-or-missing-indexes/33619#33619)

### Pivot

You want the result pivoted with one column per selected `group_id`. Use **`crosstab()`** from the additional `tablefunc` module for fastest results. If you are not familiar with it, read basic instructions here first:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    $$SELECT date_trunc('hour', to_timestamp(created / 1000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
           , group_id
           , count(*)::int
      FROM   actions
      WHERE  group_id IN (1489, 1616)  -- more?
      AND    created  >= EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date - 7) * 1000
      GROUP  BY 1, 2
      ORDER  BY 1, 2$$

   ,$$SELECT unnest('{1489, 1616}'::int[])$$
   ) AS ct (hour timestamp, "1489" int, "1616" int);  -- more?
```

Missing elements are NULL. You cannot catch this with `COALESCE` around `count()` in the inner query. Use `COALESCE` in the outer query instead. Like:

```
SELECT hour, COALESCE("1489", 0) AS "1489", COALESCE("1616", 0) AS "1616" FROM crosstab( ...
```

Note that hours without any rows are still missing in the result. Use an `OUTER JOIN` to a complete time grid if you want empty rows in the result. Like:

- [Filling in missing dates in record set from generate_series()](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72419/filling-in-missing-dates-in-record-set-from-generate-series/72620#72620)